# Getting Exception 'Cannot convert '08/10/09' to a timestamp' while connecting to Sybase Database with .Net

Tags: c#, sap-ase

When I am trying to connect Sybase with c# by using **AseClient**, I am getting -

> {"SQL Anywhere Error -157: Cannot convert '08/10/09' to a
>   timestamp"}   System.Exception {Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseException}

I dont know whats the reason

my code is:

```
var conn = new AseConnection();
conn.ConnectionString =
    "Data Source=myserver:port;" +
    "Initial Catalog=mydb;" +
    "User id=uid;" +
    "Password=pwd;";

conn.Open();
```

The error i am getting is **Cannot convert '08/10/09' to a timestamp**
I haven't used the date '08/10/09' anywhere..

This is the stacktrace:

```
=== SQL Anywhere Error -157: Cannot convert '08/10/09' to a timestamp 
    at Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseConnection.Open() 
    at Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseConnection.Open() 
    at SyBaseTest.Program.Main(String[] args) 
in D:\DotNet\RandD\SyBaseTest\Progr am.cs:line 60
```

[image: See the Image to get the ISSUE]

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that you've verified exhibits the problem, this to ensure *you* can reproduce the problem with just the connection code.

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: I highly doubt that just opening the connection throws you that exception. Check your code

Comment: Stacktrace : === SQL Anywhere Error -157: Cannot convert '08/10/09' to a timestamp
   at Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseConnection.Open()
   at Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseConnection.Open()
   at SyBaseTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\DotNet\RandD\SyBaseTest\Progr
am.cs:line 60

Comment: Have a look [here](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3646147).It may be related to your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with the Sybase DLL,
Once changed the DLL and changed the Project version to 32bit, its working